# Check for specific sequences in list

Tags: python, arrays, list

So, I have to check if to check if a sublist is present within the list and has to appear in the list in that order as well. If sublist is present in the list the function should return true. and if not it should return false. I created a function attempting to do this, can someone tell me if im on the right track or what I should fix, b/c right now it isn't working.

```
def subfunc(L,sublist):

  for i in range (len(L)):
        if L[i:i+len(sublist)] == sublist:
              print "true"
        else:
              print "false"
```

for example if the sublist was `[3,4]` and the list was `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` it should return true. In the case that the sublist was `[5,1]` it should have returned false.

Comment: "it should have returned false" - returned or printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work and handle the edge cases:

```
def subfunc(L,sublist):
    sublen = len(sublist)
    for i in xrange(len(L)-sublen+1):
        if L[i:i+sublen] == sublist:
            return True
    return False

L = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
print subfunc(L, [0,1])  # --> True
print subfunc(L, [5,1])  # --> False
print subfunc(L, [4,5])  # --> True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def check(L, subL):
...   for i in range(len(L)-len(subL)+1):
...     if L[i:i+len(subL)] == subL:
...       return True
...   return False
... 
>>> check(L, [4,5])
True
>>> check(L, [3,4])
True
>>> check(L, [5,1])
False
```

Comment: `check([0,1,2,3,4,5], [4,5])  # --> False`?

Comment: @martineau: Sorry. Fixed the off-by-one!

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the fact that you're giving out a value (true or false) for each position. Not finding the sublist on the first position does not mean it won't be found later, so you should wait until you either find it (stop the iteration and return `True` on the first position when you do find it), or you are sure you didn't (return `False` after you've gone through all elements, and they "weren't it").

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

```
def subfunc(L,sublist):
    for i in range (len(L)-len(sublist)+1):
        if L[i:i+len(sublist)] == sublist:
              return True
    return False
```

False needs to be outside of the loop, so if the loop finishes without success then false will be returned. Also, you only want to loop til len(L)-len(sublist)+1.

Comment: You were close, too. `subfunc([0,1,2,3,4,5], [4,5])  # --> False`

Comment: @martineau my bad, fixed now! cheers